# Bootstrap tagsinput

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

I downloaded the source JS and CSS for the **bootstrap-tagsinput** library from the following resource :
http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

In my asp.net website I used it in the following way :

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompany" style="font-size:x-large" runat="server" data-role="tagsinput" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Add Company" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $('input #txtCompany').tagsinput();
    alert($('input #txtCompany').val());
 </script>
```

But the alert should actually return the tags I created, but instead it returns : **`undefined`**

The JS is written in `Master Page`. All the CSS and JS references too have been mentioned in the `Master Page`.

What is the problem here ?

**EDIT :**

The TextBox is rendered as following :
[image]

**EDIT :**

With the following jQuery code i was able to retrieve the contents of the div.

```
 $('#btn').click(function () {
                var div = document.getElementById("div");
                var spans = div.getElementsByTagName("span");

                for (i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
                    alert(spans[i].innerHTML);
                }
            });
```

But the problem is that it returns the following :

[image]

And another empty alert is also shown! I don't know why!

Comment: if you don't mind please run the page then view source-code of it in the browser then bring the textbox html tag from it here so that it may helps

Comment: please see the updated question ! I added the screenshot of the source code ! @AhmedMandour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options 
first one is to replace the id with the parsed on the browser

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCompany" style="font-size:x-large" runat="server" data-role="tagsinput" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Add Company" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input #ContentPlaceHolder1_txtCompany').tagsinput();
    alert($('input #ContentPlaceHolder1_txtCompany').val());
 </script>
```

or you will add a class to the textbox as a second solution and replace the id in the jquery code with the class name not the id

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCompany" style="font-size:x-large" runat="server" data-role="tagsinput" class="form-control txtcomp" placeholder="Add Company" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input .txtcomp').tagsinput();
    alert($('input .txtcomp').val());
 </script>
```

try it and i think it's going to work

**EDIT**
you can use this function to show the added item value in alert

```
 $('input').on('itemAdded', function (event) {
     alert(event.item)
 });
```

Comment: try to add the jquery code to the bottom of the body

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="../../plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>` I have this reference already... Do i need more ?

Comment: i mean this <script type="text/javascript">
    $('input .txtcomp').tagsinput();
    alert($('input .txtcomp').val());
 </script>

Comment: Sorry couldnt save my edit ..Please see the method I tried!

Comment: Thank you so muchhhhh! :D :D Is this a standard jQuery method or is it particular to this library ?

Comment: welcome Abhishek, it's particular to the library you are using.

Comment: check this link it contains full documentation for the library
http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Answer (score 0):

You should set attribute ClientIDMode to "Static" to keep control id without parent placeholder Id in prefix. Like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCompany" ClientIDMode="Static" style="font-size:x-large" 
runat="server" data-role="tagsinput" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Add Company" />
```